# How to parse SOAP xml to get the value of a certain node

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, soap-client

I have a soap xml response and I want to get the value of the leadReferenceNumber node.

I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Here's my code:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns2:CreateLeadResponse xmlns:ns9="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/fault/SystemFault/v1.0" xmlns:ns8="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/ProductCategoryType/v1.0" xmlns:ns7="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/CampaignType/v1.0" xmlns:ns6="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/PreferredContactMethodType/v1.0" xmlns:ns5="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/LanguageType/v1.0" xmlns:ns4="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/TitleType/v1.0" xmlns:ns3="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/application/Lead/v1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/application/CRMLeadService/v1.0"><leadReferenceNumber>LP1391743548576</leadReferenceNumber></ns2:CreateLeadResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';

$soap = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$response = $soap->children();
$test = (string)$response->leadReferenceNumber;

echo $test;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using xpath. Here's the code:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns2:CreateLeadResponse xmlns:ns9="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/fault/SystemFault/v1.0" xmlns:ns8="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/ProductCategoryType/v1.0" xmlns:ns7="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/CampaignType/v1.0" xmlns:ns6="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/PreferredContactMethodType/v1.0" xmlns:ns5="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/LanguageType/v1.0" xmlns:ns4="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/TitleType/v1.0" xmlns:ns3="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/type/application/Lead/v1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.momentum.co.za/crm/service/application/CRMLeadService/v1.0"><leadReferenceNumber>LP1391743548576</leadReferenceNumber></ns2:CreateLeadResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml, NULL, NULL, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soapenv', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');

foreach($xml->xpath('//soapenv:Body') as $header)
{
    $arr = $header->xpath('//leadReferenceNumber'); // Should output 'something'.
    $leadid = $arr[0];
    echo $leadid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You surely can use xml_parse to do this, but I'd suggest, if you only need one value from a specific node, you could make use of regex which might be slightly faster especially with large xml-documents.

Documentation links:
xml_parse: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.xml-parse.php
regex (preg_match): https://www.php.net/preg_match

Hope this helps you.